# SMTP setup in Prestashop 1.7.1.1 not working

Tags: email, smtp, gmail, prestashop

I've tried everything so far but I can't make the email server to work with my G-Suite (Google Apps or Gmail) in Prestashop.

I have a G-Suite paid account that is working. I can send and receive emails. My email address is: email@mydomain.com.

I've tried leaving the first section blank "domain name" with no luck.
I've tried using smtp-relay.gmail.com instead of smtp.gmail.com with no luck
I've tried using SSL and TLS with ports: 25, 465, 587 and 2525 with no luck.

I even tried using a Gmail free account (myemail@gmail.com) and it doesn't work.

I always get the following error:

Error: Por favor compruebe su configuración
Connection could not be established with host smtp.gmail.com    [php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Name or service not known #0]

What am I doing wrong or what am I missing?

Answer (score 2):

I was able to make it work. I am not completely sure how, but I disabled G-suite's 2 way verification and insecure apps and configured the smtp with smtp.gmail.com, email@mydomain.com, password, TLS and port 587 and it finally worked.